# Replace a element in namedtupled of a nested list

Tags: list, replace, nested, element, namedtuple

I would like to edit the vote, but I cannot find how to do it. Please help

```
this_list = [Mascot(mascot_name='Peter', species='Anteater', school_name='UC Irvine', number_of_votes=137988),
Mascot(mascot_name='Victor E.', species='Bulldog', school_name='Fresno State', number_of_votes=118302),
 Mascot(mascot_name='Tuffy the Titan', species='Elephant', school_name='Cal State Fullerton', number_of_votes=94413)]
```

Edited

Comment: What element do you want to replace? What is the expected output?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

use _.replace()

```
 from collections import namedtuple
 Mascot=namedtuple('Mascot',['mascot_name','species','school_name','number_of_votes'])

 list_of_mascots = [Mascot(mascot_name='Peter', species='Anteater', school_name='UC Irvine', number_of_votes=137988),
 Mascot(mascot_name='Victor E.', species='Bulldog', school_name='Fresno State', number_of_votes=118302),
 Mascot(mascot_name='Tuffy the Titan', species='Elephant', school_name='Cal State Fullerton', number_of_votes=94413)]

for i in range(len(list_of_mascots)):
        list_of_mascots[i]=list_of_mascots[i]._replace(number_of_votes = 9)

print(list_of_mascots)
```

output:

```
 [Mascot(mascot_name='Peter', species='Anteater', school_name='UC Irvine', number_of_votes=9), Mascot(mascot_name='Victor E.', species='Bulldog', school_name='Fresno State', number_of_votes=9), Mascot(mascot_name='Tuffy the Titan', species='Elephant', school_name='Cal State Fullerton', number_of_votes=9)]
```